# Generating an increasing Nonce

Tags: python, nonce

Up until now, I have used this to generate a simple `nonce`, when authenticating with APIs:

```
def nonce():
    return str(int(time.time()) * 1000)
```

[It has now been pointed out to me](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/148983/bitex-cryptocurrency-exchange-api-framework-for-python-round-2), that this isn't entirely safe, since `time.time()` may go backwards:

```
>>> import time
>>> time.get_clock_info('time').monotonic
False
```

How would I go about generating a `nonce` instead?
My first guess was something like using `randint`, but since I need to make sure that `nonce` is always increasing, I wasn't quite sure how to ensure this, without saving a variable for future `nonce` generation - or is this uncircumventable?

Comment: how about something like `from datetime import datetime; nonce = str(datetime.now().timestamp()).replace('.', '')`? or does that have the same problem? or is that too easy to guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`time.time` will only go backward if the system clock gets updated underneath you - since DST doesn't apply to seconds-since-epoch, this should never happen on a system that keeps it clocks up to date using ntp.

A *nix specific solution is adding a check at startup to ensure ntpd is running before generating it's first nonce.  Once running, ntpd will not turn the clock back (it will just make it go forward a little bit slower than 1 second per second), so this might be a sufficient guarantee for you.

It depends entirely on your situation and appetite for risk and security trade-offs, but I would suggest this an academic concern rather than a practical one.